# Does Scala 'null' count as an instance of another type?

Tags: scala, types, parameters

I have this code:

```
class MyLinkedList[T](h: T, tail: MyLinkedList[T]) {
    def prepend(v: T): MyLinkedList[T] = new MyLinkedList(v, this) 
}
```

I wonder how it comes that I can pass the second parameter as null and it works:

```
val l: MyLinkedList[Int] = new MyLinkedList(1, null)
```

`null` is an instance of MyLinkedList[Int]?? It seems no:

```
println(null.isInstanceOf[MyLinkedList[Int]])
```

outputs `false`.

So why?

Comment: `null.isInstanceOf[MyLinkedList[Int]]` This doesn't throw a NPE? Does scala have an implicit conversion from `null` to None or something?

Comment: @Falmarri, `null` is an object in Scala (as everything else)

Comment: @ghik: How is that backwards compatible with java?

Comment: @ghik: First of all, `null` is most certainly not an object. It is the absence of an object whose type (in Scala land) is a subtype of AnyRef. Secondly, it is not true that "everything in Scala is an object." It is only true that every _value_ in Scala _may be treated as an object_ (giving the appearance of being an instance of a class). Types corresponding to Java's primitive types (subtypes of Scala's `AnyVal`) are not uniformly wrapped in class instances, but are only boxed _as needed_.

Comment: @RandallSchulz OK, my comment was not precise. I just had this in mind: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128 which states that _"all values in Scala are objects (including numerical values and functions)"_ - and if I understand well, `null` is no exception. But this of course does not mean that all values are represented as objects in the JVM/CLR.

Comment: @Falmarri: The following Java class compiles fine.

`class NullTest
{
    public
    static
    void main(String args[]) {
        if (null instanceof String)
            System.out.println("null is a String!");
        else
            System.out.println("null is not a String");
    }
}`

If executed, it prints "null is not a String".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`null` is something supported by Scala for reverse compatibility with other languages that run on the JVM and .NET framework.  The language designers aren't particularly thrilled about it but yes, it compiles just like Java code.  You should never use it in native Scala situations.  Scala provides alternatives, most idiomatically, such as `Option` with instances `Some` and `None` which is essentially a `Nullable` wrapper, for when you do need to allow a null option.

Comment: Well, first of all -- this is not an answer to my question :) Second -- how can given `class MyLinkedList` be implemented without `null`? Passing `None` to `MyLinkedList` -- `val l: MyLinkedList[Int] = new MyLinkedList(1, None)` results in compilation error: `type mismatch; found : None.type (with underlying type object None) required: Hi.MyLinkedList[Int]`

Comment: @Zapadlo You can do it without `null`, by defining an empty list in the companion object. Note that most collections in the standard library has this, such as `nil` for `List` and `empty` for `Vector`...

Comment: @Zapadio implement it by taking an `Option` as an argument, which will wrap a `Some` or `None`.  This is just a type-safe version of the null pattern.  The signature itself needs to change.

Answer (score 5):

[This blog post](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/08/20/a-post-about-nothing/) nicely explains `null` in Scala (together with [`Null`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null), [`Nil`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Nil%24), [`Nothing`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Nothing) and [`None`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.None%24)):

> `Null` is a trait, which (if you’re not familiar with traits) is sort of like an abstract class in Java. There exists exactly one instance of `Null`, and that is `null`. Not so hard. The literal `null` serves the same purpose as it does in Java. It is the value of a reference that is not refering to any object. So if you write a method that takes a parameter of type `Null`, you can only pass in two things: `null` itself or a reference of type `Null`.

Thus `null` is not an instance of any type in the Scala type system other than `Null`:

```
scala>  null.isInstanceOf[Any]
res1: Boolean = false
```

OK, so it must be an instance of `Null` then, right? Well...

```
scala>  null.isInstanceOf[Null]
<console>:8: error: type Null cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceOf test
       null.isInstanceOf[Null]
```

Overall, as others have noted, `Null` and `null` exists solely for backward compatibility with Java. Otherwise, `Null` is in the same status as `Nothing`, but the latter has no instances, and it is a more organic part of the Scala type system, as it has well defined roles in specific usage scenarios, such as defining an empty collection, or abnormally exiting from a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
class A
println(null.isInstanceOf[A])  // false
```

Although I cannot tell why but it seems that `isInstanceOf` does not work as we expect on `null`. Another way to do type checking is

```
null: MyLinkedList[Int]
```

which works.

Comment: It seems that null is some mysterious stuff not to be messed with :)