# why is it not possible to check a type as instance of `Null`

Tags: scala

Why I cannot check whether a type is `Null`?

```
scala> val s:String = null
s: String = null

scala> s.isInstanceOf[Null]
<console>:13: error: type Null cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceOf test
       s.isInstanceOf[Null]

                 ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Scala 'null' count as an instance of another type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203201/does-scala-null-count-as-an-instance-of-another-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general contract of `x.isInstanceOf[C]` is to return `true` if and only if `x` is an instance of `C`. Being "an instance of" anything implies that `x` is not null.

According to that specification, `x.isInstanceOf[Null]` must always return `false`, since `x` would not be *an instance* of `Null` even if it happens to be `null`. The compiler protects you from that confusion by refusing to compile that test instead.

The idiomatic way to test whether `x` is `null` is to simply use

```
x == null
```

Answer (score 1):

A more correct way to check for equality with `null`, since you want to look for reference equality explicity.

```
x eq null
```

Comment: `==` is commutative because `equals` is required to be commutative. Therefore, `x == null` is always the same as `null == x`, which by definition is equivalent to `x eq null`. Therefore `x == null` is just as correct as `x eq null`. From the Scala codebases I have seen, `x == null` is more idiomatic.

Comment: @sjrd You're correct, but `x eq null` is more efficient. Quoting from the _Scala_ sources: _The expression `x == that` is equivalent to `if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that)`_. So `x == null` becomes `if(x eq null) null eq null else ...` Any comparison to `null` is an explicit reference equality, rather than a value equality, so `eq` makes more sense than `==`, IMHO.

Comment: @sjrd Furthermore, if you search for `" eq null"` (with the double quotes) in _Scala_'s _GitHub_ repository, you will see lots of examples  of comparisons to `null` that are made with `eq`. So I'm not sure that your claim that `==` is more idiomatic is valid.

Comment: @sjrd. BTW, `equals` is clearly _not commutative_. The _equals contract_ dictates that `x.equals(null)` is `false`, but `null.equals(x)` is an _NPE_.

Comment: Ah, I should have been more specific. Indeed, `equals` is not commutative. What I should have said is that the specification of `equals` requires that `x.equals(null)` is always `false` when `x ne null`. This means that the desugaring of `x == null`, which as you said is `if (x eq null) that eq null else x.equals(that)` results in `if (x eq null) true else false` when `that` is `null`.  And that is clearly equivalent to `x eq null`. All Scala compilers use this equality to optimize `x == null` into `x eq null`. This means that they are both equally correct and efficient.